How can I fix the fix issue upgrading my Rails 5.2 to 6.1.7.8
My ruby version is 3.0.3, bundler version is 2.5.18
Error:
ActionView::Template::Error admin/home#index
wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)
Error in line:
<%= form_for :business, url: admin_demo_index_path, html: {class: 'no_track'}, data: {toggle: 'without_hidden_fields', disable: false}, method: :post do |f| %>

Here is my Gemfile.lock:
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/honzasterba/google-drive-ruby.git
  revision: 475f03ac7ca909697742dc794f1dad8fb52ed1b7
  specs:
    google_drive (3.0.7)
      google-apis-drive_v3 (>= 0.5.0)
      google-apis-sheets_v4 (>= 0.4.0)
      googleauth (>= 0.5.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.3)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable
  revision: 647c996f5954eac1e13347e871bded21c758572e
  branch: master
  specs:
    deep_cloneable (3.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.1.0, < 8)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.8)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.8)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.8)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.7.8)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.8)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
    activerecord (6.1.7.8)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
    activerecord-session_store (2.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2.4.1)
      activerecord (>= 5.2.4.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.11, >= 1.11.2)
      rack (>= 2.0.8, < 3)
      railties (>= 5.2.4.1)
    activestorage (6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.8)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.7.8)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    acts-as-taggable-on (8.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0, < 6.2)
    addressable (2.8.7)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 7.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    autoprefixer-rails (10.4.19.0)
      execjs (~> 2)
    axiom-types (0.1.1)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
      ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    base64 (0.2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.20)
    better_errors (2.10.1)
      erubi (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
      rouge (>= 1.0.0)
    bigdecimal (3.1.8)
    binding_of_caller (1.0.1)
      debug_inspector (>= 1.2.0)
    bootsnap (1.18.4)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.10.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    bootstrap-select-rails (1.12.4)
    bugsnag (6.27.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.3.0)
    bullet (7.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.11)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    cairo (1.17.13)
      native-package-installer (>= 1.0.3)
      pkg-config (>= 1.2.2)
      red-colors
    cairo-gobject (4.0.9)
      cairo (>= 1.16.2)
      glib2 (= 4.0.9)
    chartkick (5.0.7)
    chewy (6.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      elasticsearch (>= 6.3.0)
      elasticsearch-dsl
    childprocess (5.1.0)
      logger (~> 1.5)
    chroma (0.2.0)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    chunky_png (1.4.0)
    coercible (1.0.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
    commander (5.0.0)
      highline (~> 3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.3.4)
    connection_pool (2.4.1)
    countries (6.0.1)
      unaccent (~> 0.3)
    country_select (9.0.0)
      countries (> 5.0, < 7.0)
    crack (1.0.0)
      bigdecimal
      rexml
    crass (1.0.6)
    crypt_keeper (2.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.2, <= 7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2, <= 7)
    database_cleaner (2.0.2)
      database_cleaner-active_record (>= 2, < 3)
    database_cleaner-active_record (2.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.a)
      database_cleaner-core (~> 2.0.0)
    database_cleaner-core (2.0.1)
    datadog (2.1.0)
      debase-ruby_core_source (= 3.3.1)
      libdatadog (~> 9.0.0.1.0)
      libddwaf (~> 1.14.0.0.0)
      msgpack
    date (3.3.4)
    debase-ruby_core_source (3.3.1)
    debug_inspector (1.2.0)
    declarative (0.0.20)
    descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    devise (4.9.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-i18n (1.12.1)
      devise (>= 4.9.0)
    diff-lcs (1.5.1)
    dnsruby (1.72.2)
      simpleidn (~> 0.2.1)
    docile (1.4.1)
    domain_name (0.6.20240107)
    dotenv (3.1.4)
    dotenv-rails (3.1.4)
      dotenv (= 3.1.4)
      railties (>= 6.1)
    dry-configurable (1.2.0)
      dry-core (~> 1.0, < 2)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    dry-core (1.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    dry-inflector (1.1.0)
    dry-initializer (3.1.1)
    dry-logic (1.5.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-core (~> 1.0, < 2)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    dry-schema (1.13.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-configurable (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      dry-core (~> 1.0, < 2)
      dry-initializer (~> 3.0)
      dry-logic (>= 1.4, < 2)
      dry-types (>= 1.7, < 2)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    dry-types (1.7.2)
      bigdecimal (~> 3.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-core (~> 1.0)
      dry-inflector (~> 1.0)
      dry-logic (~> 1.4)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    elastic-transport (8.3.5)
      faraday (< 3)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch (8.15.0)
      elastic-transport (~> 8.3)
      elasticsearch-api (= 8.15.0)
    elasticsearch-api (8.15.0)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-dsl (0.1.10)
    elasticsearch-transport (7.17.11)
      base64
      faraday (>= 1, < 3)
      multi_json
    email_address (0.2.4)
      simpleidn
    equalizer (0.0.11)
    erubi (1.13.0)
    es6_promise_polyfill_rails (0.1.4)
    event_emitter (0.2.6)
    execjs (2.9.1)
    factory_bot (6.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    factory_bot_rails (6.4.3)
      factory_bot (~> 6.4)
      railties (>= 5.0.0)
    faker (3.4.2)
      i18n (>= 1.8.11, < 2)
    faraday (2.12.0)
      faraday-net_http (>= 2.0, < 3.4)
      json
      logger
    faraday-mashify (0.1.1)
      faraday (~> 2.0)
      hashie
    faraday-multipart (1.0.4)
      multipart-post (~> 2)
    faraday-net_http (3.3.0)
      net-http
    faraday-retry (2.2.1)
      faraday (~> 2.0)
    ffi (1.17.0)
    ffi-compiler (1.3.2)
      ffi (>= 1.15.5)
      rake
    fiddle (1.1.2)
    flay (2.13.3)
      erubi (~> 1.10)
      path_expander (~> 1.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.0)
    flog (4.8.0)
      path_expander (~> 1.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.1, > 3.1.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.8)
    friendly_id (5.4.2)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    fuubar (2.5.1)
      rspec-core (~> 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.4)
    fuzzy_match (2.1.0)
    gapic-common (0.22.0)
      faraday (>= 1.9, < 3.a)
      faraday-retry (>= 1.0, < 3.a)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.25, < 5.a)
      googleapis-common-protos (~> 1.6)
      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.15)
      googleauth (~> 1.11)
      grpc (~> 1.65)
    geocoder (1.6.7)
    geordi (10.1.0)
      thor (~> 1)
    gio2 (4.0.9)
      fiddle
      gobject-introspection (= 4.0.9)
    gli (2.21.5)
    glib2 (4.0.9)
      native-package-installer (>= 1.0.3)
      pkg-config (>= 1.3.5)
    globalid (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
    globalize (6.0.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.2, < 7.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.2, < 7.0)
      request_store (~> 1.0)
    globalize-accessors (0.3.0)
      globalize (>= 5.0.0)
    gobject-introspection (4.0.9)
      glib2 (= 4.0.9)
    google-apis-core (0.15.1)
      addressable (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.1)
      googleauth (~> 1.9)
      httpclient (>= 2.8.3, < 3.a)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
      mutex_m
      representable (~> 3.0)
      retriable (>= 2.0, < 4.a)
    google-apis-drive_v3 (0.57.0)
      google-apis-core (>= 0.15.0, < 2.a)
    google-apis-sheets_v4 (0.35.0)
      google-apis-core (>= 0.15.0, < 2.a)
    google-authenticator-rails (3.4.3)
      actionpack
      activerecord
      rails
      rotp (>= 5.0, < 7.0)
      rqrcode
    google-cloud-core (1.7.1)
      google-cloud-env (>= 1.0, < 3.a)
      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
    google-cloud-env (2.2.0)
      faraday (>= 1.0, < 3.a)
    google-cloud-errors (1.4.0)
    google-cloud-vision (1.5.1)
      google-cloud-core (~> 1.6)
      google-cloud-vision-v1 (>= 0.13, < 2.a)
      google-cloud-vision-v1p3beta1 (>= 0.12, < 2.a)
    google-cloud-vision-v1 (1.0.1)
      gapic-common (>= 0.21.1, < 2.a)
      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
    google-cloud-vision-v1p3beta1 (0.13.1)
      gapic-common (>= 0.21.1, < 2.a)
      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
    google-protobuf (4.28.2-arm64-darwin)
      bigdecimal
      rake (>= 13)
    google-protobuf (4.28.2-x86_64-darwin)
      bigdecimal
      rake (>= 13)
    google-protobuf (4.28.2-x86_64-linux)
      bigdecimal
      rake (>= 13)
    googleapis-common-protos (1.6.0)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.18, < 5.a)
      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.7)
      grpc (~> 1.41)
    googleapis-common-protos-types (1.16.0)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.18, < 5.a)
    googleauth (1.11.0)
      faraday (>= 1.0, < 3.a)
      google-cloud-env (~> 2.1)
      jwt (>= 1.4, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.11)
      os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
      signet (>= 0.16, < 2.a)
    grocer (0.7.1)
    groupdate (6.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
    grpc (1.66.0-arm64-darwin)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.25, < 5.0)
      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
    grpc (1.66.0-x86_64-darwin)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.25, < 5.0)
      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
    grpc (1.66.0-x86_64-linux)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.25, < 5.0)
      googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
    hashdiff (1.1.1)
    hashie (5.0.0)
    highline (3.0.1)
    htmlcompressor (0.4.0)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    http (5.2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      base64 (~> 0.1)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0)
      http-form_data (~> 2.2)
      llhttp-ffi (~> 0.5.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.7)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    http-form_data (2.3.0)
    http_accept_language (2.1.1)
    httpclient (2.8.3)
    i18n (1.8.11)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    i18n-js (3.9.2)
      i18n (>= 0.6.6)
    icalendar (2.10.3)
      ice_cube (~> 0.16)
      ostruct
    ice_cube (0.17.0)
    ice_nine (0.11.2)
    image_processing (0.11.2)
    iso-639 (0.3.6)
    iso4217 (001)
    jaro_winkler (1.6.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-dirtyforms-rails (2.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.6.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (7.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    jquery_mask_rails (0.1.0)
    json (2.7.2)
    json-compare (0.1.8)
    jsonb_accessor (1.3.10)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
      pg (>= 0.18.1)
    jwt (2.9.1)
      base64
    launchy (3.0.1)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      childprocess (~> 5.0)
    lefthook (1.7.17)
    letter_opener (1.10.0)
      launchy (>= 2.2, < 4)
    libdatadog (9.0.0.1.0)
    libdatadog (9.0.0.1.0-x86_64-linux)
    libddwaf (1.14.0.0.0-arm64-darwin)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    libddwaf (1.14.0.0.0-x86_64-darwin)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    libddwaf (1.14.0.0.0-x86_64-linux)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    libv8-node (16.19.0.1-arm64-darwin)
    libv8-node (16.19.0.1-x86_64-darwin)
    libv8-node (16.19.0.1-x86_64-linux)
    lightbox2-rails (2.8.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    listen (3.9.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    llhttp-ffi (0.5.0)
      ffi-compiler (~> 1.0)
      rake (~> 13.0)
    logger (1.6.1)
    lograge (0.12.0)
      actionpack (>= 4)
      activesupport (>= 4)
      railties (>= 4)
      request_store (~> 1.0)
    loofah (2.22.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    mail (2.8.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    mailgun-ruby (1.2.14)
      rest-client (>= 2.0.2)
    marcel (1.0.4)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.1.0)
    mime-types (3.5.2)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2024.0903)
    mimemagic (0.4.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rake
    mini_magick (5.0.1)
    mini_mime (1.1.5)
    mini_racer (0.6.4)
      libv8-node (~> 16.19.0.0)
    minitest (5.25.1)
    msgpack (1.7.2)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multipart-post (2.4.1)
    mutex_m (0.2.0)
    native-package-installer (1.1.9)
    net-http (0.4.1)
      uri
    net-imap (0.4.16)
      date
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.2)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.5.0)
      net-protocol
    netrc (0.11.0)
    next_rails (1.4.0)
      rainbow (>= 3)
    nio4r (2.7.3)
    nokogiri (1.16.7-arm64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.16.7-x86_64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.16.7-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    observer (0.1.2)
    oj (3.11.8)
    open4 (1.3.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    os (1.1.4)
    ostruct (0.6.0)
    paper_trail (12.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.2)
      request_store (~> 1.1)
    parallel (1.26.3)
    parallel_tests (4.7.2)
      parallel
    parser (3.3.5.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
      racc
    passbook (0.4.4)
      commander
      grocer
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
      terminal-table
    path_expander (1.1.3)
    pg (1.5.8)
    pgreset (0.4)
    pkg-config (1.5.6)
    poppler (4.0.9)
      cairo-gobject (= 4.0.9)
      gio2 (= 4.0.9)
    public_suffix (6.0.1)
    puma (6.4.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rabl (0.15.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
    racc (1.8.1)
    rack (2.2.9)
    rack-cors (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 2.0.0)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.7.8)
      actioncable (= 6.1.7.8)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.7.8)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      actiontext (= 6.1.7.8)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.8)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.8)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.8)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.8)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.7.8)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      minitest
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    rails-i18n (6.0.0)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      railties (>= 6.0.0, < 7)
    rails-pg-extras (5.4.0)
      rails
      ruby-pg-extras (= 5.4.0)
    rails_dt (1.2.0)
    railties (6.1.7.8)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.8)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.8)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.11.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    red-colors (0.4.0)
      json
      matrix
    redis (4.8.1)
    reek (6.3.0)
      dry-schema (~> 1.13.0)
      parser (~> 3.3.0)
      rainbow (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      rexml (~> 3.1)
    regexp_parser (2.9.2)
    representable (3.2.0)
      declarative (< 0.1.0)
      trailblazer-option (>= 0.1.1, < 0.2.0)
      uber (< 0.2.0)
    request_store (1.7.0)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    responders (3.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      railties (>= 5.2)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    retriable (3.1.2)
    rexml (3.3.7)
    rmagick (6.0.1)
      observer (~> 0.1)
      pkg-config (~> 1.4)
    rotp (6.3.0)
    rouge (4.4.0)
    rqrcode (2.2.0)
      chunky_png (~> 1.0)
      rqrcode_core (~> 1.0)
    rqrcode_core (1.2.0)
    rspec-core (3.13.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.13.3)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.13.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-rails (6.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 6.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
      railties (>= 6.1)
      rspec-core (~> 3.13)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.13)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.13)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13)
    rspec-support (3.13.1)
    rspec_junit_formatter (0.6.0)
      rspec-core (>= 2, < 4, != 2.12.0)
    rubocop (1.21.0)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.0.0.0)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.9.1, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.32.3)
      parser (>= 3.3.1.0)
    rubocop-checkstyle_formatter (0.6.0)
      rubocop (>= 1.14.0)
    rubocop-performance (1.19.1)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 0.4.0)
    rubocop-rails (2.12.4)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.1)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
    rubocop-rspec (2.11.1)
      rubocop (~> 1.19)
    ruby-pg-extras (5.4.0)
      pg
      terminal-table
    ruby-progressbar (1.13.0)
    ruby_parser (3.21.1)
      racc (~> 1.5)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.16)
    rubycritic (4.6.1)
      flay (~> 2.8)
      flog (~> 4.4)
      launchy (>= 2.0.0)
      parser (>= 2.6.0)
      rainbow (~> 3.0)
      reek (~> 6.0, < 7.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.8)
      simplecov (>= 0.17.0)
      tty-which (~> 0.4.0)
      virtus (~> 1.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    sexp_processor (4.17.2)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    sidekiq (6.5.12)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5, < 3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      redis (>= 4.5.0, < 5)
    signet (0.19.0)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      faraday (>= 0.17.5, < 3.a)
      jwt (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    simplecov (0.22.0)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
      simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
    simplecov-html (0.13.1)
    simplecov-json (0.2.3)
      json
      simplecov
    simplecov-rcov (0.3.7)
      simplecov (>= 0.4.1)
    simplecov_json_formatter (0.1.4)
    simpleidn (0.2.3)
    slack-ruby-client (2.4.0)
      faraday (>= 2.0)
      faraday-mashify
      faraday-multipart
      gli
      hashie
    sort_alphabetical (1.1.0)
      unicode_utils (>= 1.2.2)
    sprockets (4.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 6.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stackprof (0.2.26)
    telephone_number (1.4.21)
    terminal-table (3.0.2)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
    terser (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    thor (1.3.2)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.4.0)
    timeout (0.4.1)
    tinymce-rails (7.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
    traceroute (0.8.1)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    trailblazer-option (0.1.2)
    tty-which (0.4.2)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    uber (0.1.0)
    unaccent (0.4.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.6.0)
    unicode_utils (1.4.0)
    uniform_notifier (1.16.0)
    uri (0.13.1)
    useragent (0.16.10)
    virtus (1.0.5)
      axiom-types (~> 0.1)
      coercible (~> 1.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.3)
      equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    webmock (3.23.1)
      addressable (>= 2.8.0)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff (>= 0.4.0, < 2.0.0)
    websocket (1.2.11)
    websocket-client-simple (0.8.0)
      event_emitter
      websocket
    websocket-driver (0.7.6)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    whenever (1.0.0)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)
    wicked_pdf (2.0.2)
      activesupport
    wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.6.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.18)

PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin
  x86_64-darwin
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-session_store (= 2.0.0)
  acts-as-taggable-on (~> 8.1.0)
  addressable
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller (~> 1.0.0)
  bootsnap (>= 1.12.0)
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.7)
  bootstrap-select-rails (~> 1.12.4)
  bugsnag
  bullet
  byebug
  chartkick
  chewy (~> 6.0.0)
  chroma (~> 0.2.0)
  country_select
  crypt_keeper
  database_cleaner
  datadog (~> 2.1.0)
  deep_cloneable!
  devise (~> 4.9, >= 4.9.4)
  devise-i18n (~> 1.12, >= 1.12.1)
  dnsruby
  dotenv-rails
  elasticsearch (~> 8.8)
  elasticsearch-api (~> 8.15)
  elasticsearch-transport (~> 7.17, >= 7.17.11)
  email_address
  es6_promise_polyfill_rails
  factory_bot_rails
  faker (>= 2.17.0)
  friendly_id (~> 5.4.2)
  fuubar (~> 2.0)
  fuzzy_match
  geocoder (~> 1.6.7)
  geordi
  globalize (~> 6.0.1)
  globalize-accessors
  google-authenticator-rails (~> 3.4.2)
  google-cloud-vision
  google-protobuf
  google_drive!
  groupdate
  htmlcompressor
  htmlentities
  http (~> 5.2.0)
  http_accept_language
  i18n (~> 1.8.11)
  i18n-js (~> 3.9.2)
  icalendar
  image_processing
  iso-639
  iso4217
  jaro_winkler
  jbuilder (~> 2.11.2)
  jquery-dirtyforms-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  jquery_mask_rails (~> 0.1.0)
  json (>= 2.5.1)
  json-compare
  jsonb_accessor (~> 1.3.4)
  lefthook
  letter_opener
  lightbox2-rails
  listen
  lograge (~> 0.12.0)
  mailgun-ruby (~> 1.2.5)
  mimemagic
  mini_magick
  mini_racer (~> 0.6.4)
  next_rails
  oj (~> 3.11.5)
  open4
  paper_trail (~> 12.3.0)
  parallel_tests
  parser
  passbook
  pg (~> 1.5.3)
  pgreset
  poppler (~> 4.0.5)
  puma (~> 6.4.2)
  rabl (~> 0.15.0)
  rack-cors
  rails (~> 6.1.0)
  rails-i18n (~> 6.0)
  rails-pg-extras
  rails_dt (~> 1.2.0)
  rake (~> 13.0.06)
  rest-client (~> 2.0.2)
  rmagick
  rqrcode
  rspec-rails (~> 6.1.0)
  rspec_junit_formatter
  rubocop (~> 1.21.0)
  rubocop-checkstyle_formatter
  rubocop-performance
  rubocop-rails (~> 2.12.2)
  rubocop-rspec
  ruby-progressbar
  rubycritic (~> 4.6.1)
  rubyzip
  sass-rails
  sassc-rails
  shoulda-matchers (~> 3.1, >= 3.1.1)
  sidekiq (~> 6.5.7)
  simplecov
  simplecov-json
  simplecov-rcov
  simpleidn (~> 0.2.1)
  slack-ruby-client
  sort_alphabetical
  sprockets
  stackprof
  telephone_number
  terser
  tinymce-rails
  traceroute
  uri (~> 0.13.1)
  useragent
  webmock
  websocket-client-simple
  whenever
  wicked_pdf (~> 2.0.2)
  wkhtmltopdf-binary (~> 0.12.6.5)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.3p157

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.18


Look at the stack trace again. The line that you have presented here cannot be the culprit as the signature is form_for(record, options = {}, &block) which gives it an arity of 1..2 not 0..1. You're also just passing two arguments.

Thanks @max for the clarity but I am not able to understand then why it is breaking? In my logs in staging server it's showing this line but in my local machine it's working.

There has been a change in params, especially autosplatting the last keyworded arguments. You may have to write the helper with proper hash curly braces: form_for :business, { url: admin_demo_index_path, html: {class: 'no_track'}, data: {toggle: 'without_hidden_fields', disable: false}, method: :post} do |f|

I tried this but did not work. Struggling from past 3 hours :(

Can you post the full stacktrace?

I'm guessing you've upgraded to ruby 3.0.3 as well?
Ruby 3.0 removed the ability for keyword arguments and argument objects to be used interchangeably
In ruby 2.7,  for a function `def do_the_thing(options), you could call it with
`do_the_thing(a: 1, b: 2)`

or
do the thing({a: 1, b: 2})
However, ruby 3 removed this functionality, so now you must define whether you expect keyword arguments or an options hash parameter. Based on the error message, rails's form_for is expecting an options hash. Try wrapping the keyword arguments in a hash {...}

Thank you for the help but I have tried that too it isn't working. The think is everything is working fine in my local development environment but as soon as I move to staging server my renders, link_to, form_for and routes path is breaking with the same ActionView::Template error wrong number of arguments. I have compared my gem env, bundler version, Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in both my development and staging everything is same but still it breaks. I am not sure why it's happening!.

I have found the solution after hours of debugging. The culprit was
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

which was interfering with the ActiveSupport url_for method.
I removed it from a file which is it not required and the issue resolved.
Hope it helps others.
